# Convert NSString to NSDate with new format

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

This question was asked a lot, but I can't find the solution for my problem.

**What I want**:
Convert a date given as a NSString into a NSDate with a complete different format.
I want to convert `Tue, 31 Jul 2012 10:15:00 GMT` to `2012-07-31 10:15:00 +0000`.

**My code**:

```
NSString *startDateString = @"Tue, 31 Jul 2012 10:15:00 GMT"; //in real from a server

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startDateString];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'"];

NSString *endDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:startDate];
NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:endDateString];
```

**Problem**:
`endDate` is `nil`.

**Edit**:
Found a strange behaviour.
When I change the first dateFormat to `@"EEE, dd MMM yyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"` (added GMT) then the output of endDate is correct, but **only** in the Simulator. On the device it is still nil.
With the dateFormat without "GMT" the value is nil on the Simulator and on the Device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working well for me, you might use it:

```
NSString *startDateString = @"Tue, 31 Jul 2012 10:15:00 GMT"; //in real from a server

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZZZ"]; // SPOT the difference in this line

NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startDateString];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"]; // and SPOT the difference in this line

NSString *endDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:startDate];
NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:endDateString];

NSLog(@"%@", endDate);
```

the `endDate` is:

```
2012-07-31 10:15:00 +0000
```

**UPDATE #1**

it has been **tested on the real device** only!

Comment: Thanks! This works. I have to set the locale for the formatter to en_US: `[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]`, because my locale is in default "de_DE" and this seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following before converting

```m
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```