# Convert NSString to NSDate Format in Specific date format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert NSString to NSDate with new format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761381/convert-nsstring-to-nsdate-with-new-format)

I have a `NSString` **@"Tue, 24 May 2011 0:05:01"** value which i want to convert in `NSDate` formate like
dd/mm/yyyy
so please suggest us how we can do this

Comment: I have got the solution
NSString *startDateString = @"Tue, 31 Jul 2012 10:15:00"; //in real from a server
    
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"]; // SPOT the difference in this line
    
    NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startDateString];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"]; // and SPOT the difference in this line
    
    NSString *endDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:startDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", endDateString);

Comment: NSString *strDate = @"Tuesday, 24 May 2011 0:05:01";
        
    NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *inputDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
    
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/YYYY"];
    
    NSString *outputString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate];
    
    NSLog(@"Date  ::  >>  %@",outputString);

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"]; 
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:DatePicker.date];
```

Hope this helps ! :)